# Fourier Transform of f(t)=|t|

Tags: fourier-analysis

This is a question on taking the Fourier transform of a function.

How does one find the fourier transform of $f$, where $f(t) = |t|$?

Comment: See [**Fourier Transform**](http://www.thefouriertransform.com/pairs/absT.php). Can you follow the derivation?

Comment: This helps a lot; thanks.  I'm surprised that we'd have to deal with derivatives of dirac deltas to solve this problem; I thought it would be simpler than that since it came on a midterm.

Comment: @user24205: without any additional trick you can define the Fourier transform only when $\int dt\,f(t)e^{i\omega t}$ converges. For your example, this integral is diverging as it stands...

Comment: You can check the result using [**WA**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fourier+transform+abs%28t%29)

Comment: It boils down thinking about how use the signum function to express the absolute value and then using the definitions for Fourier Transform. I would go through the example and make sure you can follow the entire derivation. Have fun!